# NO VISUALIZA INFORMACIÓN EN TABLA ANGULAR CONSUMIDA POR API - SPRINBOOT

Tags: java, angular

Tengo una situación en mi proyecto y es que estoy intentando hacer que se visualice la información consumida mediante un API usando **Spring Boot** para mostrarla a través de **Angular**.
Esta información se logro capturar de manera satisfactoria, pero como lo indico, no se logra mostrar en una tabla sencilla en el **HTMl** de **Angular**.

El servicio en **Angular** lo estoy realizando de está manera:

```js
 private URL: string = 'http://localhost:8080';
 platos = [];

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getPlatos():Observable<PlatoModel[]>{
   return this.http.get<PlatoModel[]>('/api/platos');
 }
```

Ahora en el componente de **Plato** lo tengo de está manera

```js
  platos: PlatoModel[] = [];

  constructor(private platoService: PlatoService, private router: Router) { 
    this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.platoService.getPlatos().subscribe(resp => {
      this.platos = resp;
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }
```

Y justo en el HTML del componente lo tengo de está manera:

```html
      <tr *ngFor="let plato of platos">
        <td scope="row">{{ plato.idPlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.nombrePlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.descripcionPlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.cantidadPlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.precioPlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.imagenPlato }}</td>
        <td>{{ plato.clasificacionPlato }}</td>
      </tr>
```

Sin embargo, esto es lo único que logro visualizar en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no entiendo por qué no se visualiza la información, considero que estoy haciendo todo lo correcto.
Sí me podrían ayudar, les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te está reconociendo la directiva ngFor, lo que seguramente significa que te falta un módulo básico de Angular por importar, `BrowserModule`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],  
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Realmente allí estaba la solución, me faltó agregar el componente que en este caso se llama: **PlatoComponent** a las declaraciones dentro del **@NgModule**, anteriormente se me agregaban automáticamente, ahora debo hacerlas manualmente. Muchas gracias, llevaba varias horas allí sin poder avanzar.